# PyCharm, range, Expected type '_SupportsIndex', got 'int' instead

Tags: python, pycharm, range

How to clear these annoying yellow things?

> Expected type '_SupportsIndex', got 'int' instead

They were not there when I didn't have a GitHub Desktop app OR when I didn't have PyCharm updated.

```py
str0 = input()
str1 = input()
k = str1.count(str0)
i = 0
for i in range(k, 0, -1):
    if (str0 * i) in str1:
        break
print(i)
```

This is what PyCharm shows me:

[image: This is what PyCharm shows me]

Comment: Not sure what the code does, but when I paste the code into PyCharm I do not get these warnings. Maybe update the app

Comment: This doesn't happen with an updated PyCharm using standard inspection settings. Couldn't reproduce.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File -> Manage IDE Settings -> Restore Default Settings